Difference of attributes between two shapefiles based on similar field in QGIS
My issue is best shown using tables (the issue is only with shapefiles in QGIS):
pre-culvert.shp:



element_no
depth




1
10


4
3



post-culvert.shp:



element_no
depth




30
44


4
6



Looking for the following output:
New.shp



element_no
afflux




1
10-0=10


4
3-6=-3


30
0-44=-44



Basically, need to find the difference of "element_no" between two shapefiles. but I also need to include "element_no" that does not exist between each.

What to implement with their geometries, do features #4 posses the same geometries in both layers pre-culvert.shp and post-culvert.shp ?

You can create a virtual layer and use coalesce

The coalesce() function accepts two or more arguments and returns the
first non-null argument.

with
full outer join

The FULL OUTER JOIN keyword returns all records when there is a match
in left (table1) or right (table2) table records.

Then Load the layer, right-click and Export as a shapefile.
select  row_number() over() as new_id,
        coalesce(pre.element_no, post.element_no) as element_no,
        coalesce(pre.depth, 0) - coalesce(post.depth, 0) as afflux,
        coalesce(pre.geometry, post.geometry) as geometry
from "pre-culvert" as pre
full outer join "post-culvert" as post
on pre.element_no = post.element_no


